# Join on data from XML in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, join

I have the following XML message:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SET @XML = 
'<Message>
<Changes>
    <Deleted>
        <ROW id="1" name="Nicole" surname="Bartlett" city="denver" balance="779.4663" dateOfBirth="1991-12-11T14:05:42.830" maritalStatus="S" />
        <ROW id="1" name="Nicole" surname="Bartlett" city="boston" balance="779.4663" dateOfBirth="1991-12-11T14:05:42.830" maritalStatus="S" />
    </Deleted>
    <Inserted>
        <ROW id="1" name="Nicole" surname="Bartlett" city="denver" balance="779.4663" dateOfBirth="1991-12-11T14:05:42.830" maritalStatus="S" />
        <ROW id="1" name="Nicole" surname="Bartlett" city="boston" balance="779.4663" dateOfBirth="1991-12-11T14:05:42.830" maritalStatus="S" />
    </Inserted>
</Changes>
</Message>'
```

And I need to select data from this message and join another table on id field. The following code doesn't work:

```
SELECT T.c.value('./@id', 'int') as id, t.c.value('./@name', 'varchar(max)') as name 
FROM @XML.nodes('/Message/Changes/Deleted/ROW') T(c)
inner join other_table tbl
    on tbl.id = id
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT T.c.value('./@id', 'int') as id, t.c.value('./@name', 'varchar(max)') as name 
FROM @XML.nodes('/Message/Changes/Deleted/ROW') T(c)
inner join other_table tbl
    on tbl.id = T.c.value('./@id', 'int')
```